# How to have a variable of a class which has been defined after current class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

This is my C++ CLI code:

```
public ref class SVeh{
public:
    bool Is( Pla^ For);
};
```

The `Pla` is defined after `SVeh`.

```
public ref class Pla{
public:
    bool somemethod();
};
```

Compiler takes class `Pla` as unknown identifier and doesn't compile this.
How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know C++/CLI, but if it's similar to C++, you can forward-declare Pla:

```
ref class Pla;
public ref class SVeh{
  // rest of code
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110307/c-cli-forward-declarations) for more information.

Comment: @juanchopanza What isn't C++, the code I provided or the code Mahdi posted?

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, that's why I prefaced my question with "I don't know C++/CLI, **but** if it's similar to C++". I used the C++ forward declaration syntax in his code figuring it'd work if my assumption were true. It should be C++/CLI compliant now though.

Comment: @Mahdi Had a typo in my code, did you try it like this? `ref class Pla;`

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña Yes I wrote `ref class Pla`

Comment: C++/CLI inherited the C++ behavior, it is only a single-pass compiler.  .NET programmers are not used to that, all other .NET languages have multi-pass compilers.  You'll also have to explain how to keep the declaration and the implementation of the class separate, like you do in C++.

Comment: @Mahdi how come, I've been using something like this in my codes(which works), are your classes under a namespace? if it is, you should put the ref class Pla; inside the namespace too

Comment: @GeraldSv Seems like I had to move my definitions outside the header.